# Button blink with JAVA swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, timer

I'm trying to code a methode where my button changes the Backgroundcolor. However it shall change with a blink that gets every time faster until the destined color shows up completely. The result is nothing happens. I used the timer for implemting the methode but it won't work. INSTANCE is MyActionListener. Bg1 is Backgroundcolor black and Bg2 is green.

```
    public void blink() {
        
        new javax.swing.Timer(300, INSTANCE);
        
        if (count>=maxcount) {
            new javax.swing.Timer(100, INSTANCE);
            if (button.getBackground() == Bg1) {
                button.setBackground(Bg2);
                
            }else {
                button.setBackground(Bg1);
            
            }
            
        }else {
            if (button.getBackground() == Bg1) {
                button.setBackground(Bg2);
                count ++;
                
            }else {
                button.setBackground(Bg1);
                count ++;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Hint: dont try learn a complex GUI framework like swing by trial and error. Rather pick up a tutorial, and read about the things you intend to you. CREATING a timer is only the first step, you have to START it, too. Which any basic tutorial like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html can tell you. So: always do real research when using a library component. Do not **assume** how it *might* be working. Read its documentation, read tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things with your code.

1. What is the "INSTANCE" constant?  this should be an ActionListener instance containing the code you want the timer to perform (This is a different Action than what you attach to your button).  I am assuming that you want the code block following the timer to be the action.

Start with the inner timer could look like this:

```
Timer innerTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (button.getBackground() == Bg1) {
            button.setBackground(Bg2);
            
        }else {
            button.setBackground(Bg1);
        
        }
    }
});
```

2. You never start or stop your timer.

   ```
     innerTimer.start();
     innerTimer.stop();
   ```

Here is how your blink method might look, but you will probably have to change how your counter works & I think you can do it with one timer instead of nesting them.

```
Timer innerTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (button.getBackground() == Bg1) {
            button.setBackground(Bg2);
            
        }else {
            button.setBackground(Bg1);
        
        }
    }
});


public void blink() {
    
    Timer outerTimer = new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            if (count>=maxcount) {
                innerTimer.start();
            }else {
                // is this the stop condition???
                innerTimer.stop();
                outerTimer.stop();
                if (button.getBackground() == Bg1) {
                    button.setBackground(Bg2);
                    count ++;
                    
                }else {
                    button.setBackground(Bg1);
                    count ++;
                }
                
            }
        }
    });

    outerTimer.start();
}
```

Here is a good example that I found [javacodegeeks.com](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/timer-swing/java-swing-timer-example/)

Comment: Also, Color values need to be compared with the `equals` method, not with `==`.